# How to use google chart in angularjs with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-scope

Im using angular google chart in my application, it is working fine with static data -.

```
    var chart1 = {};
  chart1.type = "GeoChart";
  chart1.data = [
        ['Locale', 'Count'],
        ['Germany', 22],
        ['United States', 34],
        ['Brazil', 42],
        ['Canada', 57],
        ['France', 6],
        ['RU', 72]
      ];

  chart1.options = {
      width: 600,
      height: 300,
      chartArea: {left:10,top:10,bottom:0,height:"100%"},
      colorAxis: {colors: ['#aec7e8', '#1f77b4']},
      displayMode: 'regions'
  };

  chart1.formatters = {
     number : [{
       columnNum: 1,
       pattern: "$ #,##0.00"
     }]
   };

  $scope.chart = chart1;
```

but im getting data from server -

```
$http.get("http://someurl")
    .success(function(response) {
$scope.data = response;});
});
```

Now how can i push the `response data` to `chart1.data` to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that success response callback function is in same controller as `chart` define.

```
$http.get("http://someurl")
    .success(function(response) {
         $scope.chart.data = response;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks sarjan i have moved all the data inside success.